# program which print a matrix in spiral way. ( is not working fine)

Tags: c++, matrix, data-structures

I need to write a program which displays the elements of a matrix in a spiral way.My program does not work fine.Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void citireMatrice(int a[100][100], int n) // function to read a matrix
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            cout<<"a[" << i << "][" << j << "]=";
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void spiral(int a[100][100], int n)
{
    int i, j, k;
    if (n % 2==0)
    {
        k = n / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        k = n / 2 + 1;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= n - i + 1; ++j)
        {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n - i + 1; ++j)
        {
            cout << a[j][n - i + 1] << " ";
        }
        for (j = n-i; j >= i; j--)
        {
            cout << a[n - i + 1][j] << " ";
        }
        for (j = n-1;j>=i+1;j--)
        {
            cout << a[j][i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[100][100];
    int n;
    cout << "n=";
    cin >> n;
    citireMatrice(a, n);
    spiral(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter n=2 with the elements 1, 2, 3, 4 it displays 4 -858993460 and other numbers like this.Where's my mistake?

Comment: Use a debugger. Single step through the program to make sure the values of `i`, `j`, and `k` are what you expect a the time you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

You're properly using zero based indexing of arrays in `citireMatrice` but in `spiral` you're using one based indexing.

You need to start your loops at `0`, and end at `< n`.  (Consider what element of `a` will be first to be printed out.)